# Do Sinatra (rack) applications have "TempData" like ASP.NET MVC has?

Tags: ruby, asp.net-mvc, sinatra, rack

In asp.net mvc there is a method called `TempData` used for holding  temporary data. Is there anything similar to it in Sinatra?

**UPDATE**: it became **TempData**.

Comment: I guess sessions is one ur talking abt correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @AlanDert `sessions` is the what I'm talking

Comment: ViewBag is also based on sessions in ASP.NET, or course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article on the differences between ViewBag, ViewData, and TempData](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications) states:

> All three objects are available as properties of both the view and controller.

and

> ViewData is a dictionary object that you put data into, which then becomes available to the view. ViewData is a derivative of the ViewDataDictionary class, so you can access by the familiar "key/value" syntax.

and

> The ViewBag object is a wrapper around the ViewData object that allows you to create dynamic properties for the ViewBag.

Sinatra doesn't use the MVC model, it uses the Page controller model. Firstly, this means that a lot of the scaffolding needed in .Net doesn't make sense in Sinatra. Also, because we're using Ruby and not C# (or whatever), again, we miss out a lot of the boilerplate needed.

Lastly, in MVC to Page controller speak, a "controller" is basically a route. So:

```
get "/" do
  # stuff…
  haml :index
end
```

is a controller. If we're looking for a dictionary object (so, some kind of Hash) that is available to both the route and the view then [according to the documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Scopes%20and%20Binding) we're in the request scope. When you're in the request scope you have available to both:

- instance variables defined in the route.
- helpers (including the `settings` object)
- locals defined in the route explicitly passed to the view.

So this would work:

```
get "/" do
  @viewbag = {a: 1}
  haml :index
end

%p= @viewbag[:a]
%p
  This will display 1
```

or this:

```
helpers do
  def viewbag
    @viewbag ||= {}
  end
end

get "/" do
  viewbag.store :a, 1
  haml :index
end

%p= viewbag[:a]
%p
  This will display 1
```

or this:

```
get "/" do
  viewbag = {:a => 1}
  haml :index, :locals => {viewbag: viewbag}
end

%p= viewbag[:a]
%p
  This will display 1
```

(don't get confused by the different syntax and use of a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) object above)

Lastly, a ViewBag is dynamic. Well, so is a Ruby Hash, as the whole language is far more dynamic.

However, I get the feeling you asked the question looking for something else, because you've stated an *implementation* and not a *goal*. If you want to get better answers, *tell people what it is you want to achieve* as well as what you've tried, not just how you think it should be done.

Comment: it turned out that I meant TempData and not ViewBag.